# Counting number of items in a box from a MP4 video using computer vision and R

Tags: r, conv-neural-network, computer-vision

I have an MP4 video in which a person keeps putting some household items into the box(container type). Items consist chips packets, colddrink bottles, mugs etc. Sometimes even person takes out some items off from the box and puts some other item in place of that.

So, I have to design a model which keeps tracking the number of items in the box on increasing and decreasing.

How can I achieve this using R and computer Vision? As I am new to deep learning and little knowledge of python..pls suggest.

Many Thanks in Advance